# vba check for negative value

Tags: vba, excel, negative-number

I wrote a simple VBA code to check if the value of a cell is negative and if it is negative, highlight it red. For some reason, I keep getting "run-time mismatch". My code is

```
For x = 2 To 100

Set val3 = Worksheets("Summary").Cells(x, 9)
If val3.Value < 0 Then
Worksheets("Summary").Cells(x, 9).FontColorIndex = 3

End If
Next x
```

Column 9 (the column I am checking) is filled with dollar values. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You forgot a dot between Font and ColorIndex?

Comment: Can also just `val3.Font.ColorIndex = 3` rather than making it re-lookup the same cell in the loop.

Comment: Why not just use `Conditional Formatting` instead of VBA?

Comment: Hi User, if you get an answer that works for you, please give it a green check.  That way future visitors to your question can find the answer and we get credit :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code, you're simply missing a dot.

> FontColorIndex = 3

should be:

> Font.ColorIndex = 3

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub test()
   For x = 2 To 100
      Set val3 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 9)
      If val3.Value < 0 Then
         Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 9).Font.Color = RGB(99, 179, 73)
      End If
   Next x
End Sub
```

Code above works in excel 2007

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your post, I needed to change the negative numbers to zeros after a certain process - BUT I want to check them before I use them so changing the font color is useful, so this code works well for the whole sheet range until (245,50)

```
Sub negnumbers()
    For x = 1 To 245
        For y = 1 To 50
        Set val3 = Worksheets("target sheet").Cells(x, y)
        If val3.Value < 0 Then
        Worksheets("target sheet").Cells(x, y).Font.ColorIndex = 3
        Worksheets("target sheet").Cells(x, y) = 0
        End If
        Next y
    Next x
End Sub
```